# wordpress widget and post content issue

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am slightly stuck. The template i am using has a custom post type called products. When i add posts/pages here, i can get them displayed using a widget code in a page.

The widget displays the content entered into custom fields, but i can't for the life of me work out how to modify the code in order to display the content from the custompost type Content section. Any insight?

This is the code from the shortcodes.php file which produces the widget.

```
   $count_posts = wp_count_posts('product');
    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;
    $out ='';
    $out .=' <div class="pricing-table">';
        $out .= '<ul>';
        $counter = 0; 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $counter++;
        $product_price = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_product_price',true);
          $out .= '<li class="heading-column '.$class_heading.' color'.$counter.'">';
            $out .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
            $out .= '<h5>';
            $out .= $currency ? $currency : "&#36;";
            $out .= $product_price;
            if ($billing_cycle == "none") {
              $out .= ""; 
            } else {
              $out .= ' per '.$billing_cycle; 
            }
            $out .= '</h5>';
          $out .= '</li>';
        endwhile;
        $out .= '</ul>';  

        $out .= '<div class="clear"></div>';
        $out .= '<ul>';
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $product_url = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_product_url',true);
        $product_feature = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_product_feature',true);
        $features_list = explode(",",$product_feature);
        $counter++;
          $out .= '<li class="pric-column '.$class_column;
          if ($counter%$columns==0) $out .= '-last';
          $out .= '">';
            foreach ($features_list as $flist) {
            $out .= '<ul class="feature-list">';
              $out .= '<li>'.$flist.'</li>';
            }
            $out .= '<li class="last">';
            $out .= '<a class="button" href="'.$product_url.'"><span>'.$product_button_text.'</span></a>';
            $out .= '</li>';
            $out .= '</ul>';  
      endwhile;wp_reset_query();
      $out .= '</ul>';  
  $out .= '</div>';

  return '[raw]'.$out.'[/raw]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't work because [`the loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/the_loop) doesn't get filled.
There for it will do the default loop of the page. (if it hasn't run already that is)

Also you do stuff that does nothing like `$published_posts`.

You should create a custom loop with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

A little help to get you started:

```
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products', // the post type name
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$products = new WP_Query ($query_args)

// before loop stuff like opening tags
while($products->have_posts()): $products->the_post();
    // do your stuff like display post_meta
endwhile;
// after loop stuff like closing tags
```

This should get you started.
If you need any help, let me know!